# JSFL - Adding a movieclip to a specific layer and frame

Tags: jsfl

I am trying to replace an outdated movieclip with a newer one.

To do this I'm usin JSFL to locate the old movieclips, save a reference, then add the new version in its place.

I have looked at addItem addItemToDocument and they successfully add the clip, but I'm unsure of how to add it to the specific layer and frame that the old instance of the movieclip was on.

Halps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing all instances of the old movieclip with instances of the new movieclip, could be an easier solution.
All instances of the old movieclip can be found by parsing the timelines of the flash document.
Here is some code:

```
var _doc = (fl.getDocumentDOM() ? fl.getDocumentDOM() : fl.createDocument());
var _lib = _doc.library;
fl.outputPanel.clear();
ReplaceItemWithItem('Game Layouts/card holder', 'Game Layouts/card holder new');
function ReplaceItemWithItem(oldmcname, newmcname)
{
  var item1 = GetItem(oldmcname);
  var item2 = GetItem(newmcname);
  if (!item1) return false;
  if (!item2) return false;
  if (oldmcname == newmcname)
    return true;
  return ReplaceAllItems(item1, item2);
}
function ReplaceAllItems(item1, item2)
{
  var timelines = _doc.timelines;
  var i, l = timelines.length;
  var items = _lib.items;
  var changed = false;
// Main timelines
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
  {
    var timeline = timelines[i];
    changed |= ReplaceItems(timeline, item1, item2);
  }
// Timelines in library items
  for (i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++)
  {
    var item = items[i];
    switch (item.itemType)
    {
    case "movie clip":
    case "graphic":
    case "button":
      changed |= ReplaceItems(item.timeline, item1, item2);
      break;
    }
  }
  return changed;
}
function ReplaceItems(timeline, item1, item2)
{
  var changed = false;
  if (timeline && item1 && item2)
  {
    var layers = timeline.layers;
    var lay, layl = layers.length;
    for (lay = 0; lay < layl; lay++)
    {
      var layer = layers[lay];
      var frames = layer.frames;
      var fr, frl = frames.length;
      for (fr = 0; fr < frl; fr++)
      {
        var frame = frames[fr];
        if (frame && frame.startFrame == fr)
        {
          var elements = frame.elements;
          var e, el = elements.length;
          for (e = 0; e < el; e++)
          {
            var elem = elements[e];
            if (elem && elem.elementType == "instance")  // Elements can be empty
            {
              var item = elem.libraryItem;
              if (item.name == item1.name)
              {
                elem.libraryItem = item2;
                changed = true;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return changed;
}
function GetItem(itemname)
{
  if (!_lib.selectItem(itemname))
  {
    alert("'" + name + "' does not exist in the library!");
    return null;
  }
  return _lib.getSelectedItems()[0];
}
```

Hope this helps!